# Can I use Kafka between Logstash and Elasticsearch? ( Using two Kafka)

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, elastic-stack

I'm trying to integrate **Apache Kafka** with **Elastic Stack**(Beats, Logstash, Elasticsearch, and Kibana)

[image]

From the diagram, Kafka is located between Beats and Logstash. I was wondering **if I can put another Kafka between Logstash and Elasticsearch.** (Where I drew with a red pen.)

Two Kafka sound okay?

Any ideas or thoughts to share?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose? How would you then stream data from Kafka directly into ES?

Comment: @Val  I was just curious. I heard Neflix uses two Kafka Systems(?) so I  wanted to experiment (if I can)  I'll keep your advice in mind. thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

1. Logstash can write to Kafka as an output.
2. You can use [Kafka Connect Elasticsearch](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-elasticsearch/index.html) for streaming from Kafka into Elasticsearch.

If you want to buffer/scale the output from Logstash by using Kafka here, it is possible and would make sense.

But bear in mind that you could also:

(a) write from Beats to Kafka and do any processing with KSQL/Kafka Streams etc to write back to Kafka and then Kafka Connect to Elasticsearch
or
(b) just write from Logstash to Elasticsearch